# How do I adjust the corona virus situation for demand forecasting?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting

A lot of business have been hit by the current pandemic. If I want to do a demand forecast for say next 3 months, how do I adjust the corona virus situation in my model?. Which method should I use?
Thanks in advance!